# Can you display page in alternate language despite language settings

Tags: 2010, language

Using SharePoint 2010, is there a way to append the URL for a page so that it will display in a specific language despite what the user has their languages preferences set to?

For example, I want to link from a French HTML page to the French version of a SharePoint page. Right now, if the user's settings are for English, the SharePoint page will come up in English. Is there a way to force it to show the french page? Some bit that is added to the URL?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of an OOTB query string parameter to do this.

The blog post [Change current UI locale using query string parameter in Sharepoint](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.ca/2010/04/change-current-ui-locale-using-query.html) shows how to accomplish this using a customization based on an HTTP handler.

But that doesn't help if you can't deploy custom code to your farm.

Comment: No, I am just an end user in web publishing.